# When a process call the sleep function, does it emit a signal?

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

I'm forking a process in my program, and this process calls a `exec()` function, then the child process calls the `sleep()` function.

I want to know if the `sleep()` function sends some kind of signal that the parent can detect, and if so, what type of signal does it send?

Comment: Seeing how there are two contradicting answers: Those are both correct as by POSIX. It is _allowable_ for `sleep` to use `alarm`, but that is not a requirement. It may or it may not. (Under Linux/glibc it _doesn't_, but that's coincidential. Further, it still _interacts_ with `alarm` since it may be interrupted by the signal of an `alarm` call).

Comment: @Damon, I see nothing contradictory in the answers. Both say `sleep` _may_ use signals under the covers, both say that has nothing to do with the parent. If anything, they're complementary.

Comment: @paxdiablo: To me it seemed like someone reading the two side by side might be confused and easily see them as contradictory when they're really both correct (one basically saying "No, it doesn't (ok, well... it _might_, internally)" and the other saying "Yes, it _typically_ does..."). Maybe it's just me. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically `sleep()` is implemented by calling [`alarm(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) which arranges for a `SIGALRM` signal to be delivered to the calling process once timeout expires.

In other words, signal is sent after `sleep` is finished sleeping, just not to the parent process - but to process which called `sleep`. And parent process cannot intercept signals delivered to its child.

Comment: This implementation is anything but typical and not even valid on a modern multithreaded implementation. The next issue (or maybe even TC) of POSIX will clarify this.

Comment: @R..: from Linux [`alarm(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html): `sleep(3)` may be implemented using `SIGALRM`; mixing calls to `alarm()` and `sleep(3)` is a bad idea. `sleep(3)` man page has exact same paragraph as well.

Comment: On 25-year-old non-Linux systems.

Comment: Mostly a wrapper around the nanosleep syscall on Linux these days from what I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

No, `sleep` itself doesn't send any sort of signal to the parent, it may use signals under the covers to wake itself up, but that's totally internal to the child.

If you want to notify the *parent,* you'll have to do that yourself before sleeping. That may be as simple as:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
:
kill (getppid(), SIGHUP);
```

Comment: This code is racy. The parent could terminate between `getppid` and `kill`, signaling the wrong process.

Comment: @R, yes. The parent would have to exit _and_ another process start with exactly the same PID, a situation almost ludicrously unlikely but certainly _possible._ Unfortunately, just about any solution is going to have that problem, all you can do is minimise it.

Comment: Only solutions involving signals (which are almost always the wrong solution) have this problem. There are plenty of valid ways of communicating with a parent process like pipes or shared memory.